# Android Studio is getting stuck at Git Log Indexing and becomes non-responsive

Tags: android-studio

My Android project is a very huge one with numerous files and directories.
After launching the project, the Android Studio shows `Git Log Indexing...` and stuck forever.

Is there an explanation why this step takes so long?